# how to implement infinite scroll in wordpress archive page

Tags: wordpress

I am having trouble implementing automatically loading more articles when i reach the bottom of the page in wordpress archive page.

I have tried using jetpack but no success.

Comment: What's the problem in implementing logic ????
Any error or confusion ?

Comment: Before deciding to implement infinite scroll, read this article about the usefulness of this design pattern: http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/03/infinite-scrolling-get-bottom/

Comment: @AkshayPaghdar I have implemented it using jetpack, but its nor working. I heard that jetpack infinite scroll will not work in wordpress archive page.. is it true?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jscroll - you may find it usefull :

http://jscroll.com/